# How to solve problem related to black screen with cursor only after loging in?

Tags: ubuntu

Suddenly, I got crash report after logging in to my primary account. It says "cannot open display". But, everything work just fine while loging in with "Guest" account. I tried using these methods which didn't work for me:

METHOD 1:

After getting that black screen I pressed ctrl + alt + f1 key, then after loging in with primary username. I started typing these command:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get intall --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

METHOD 2

```
cp .config/dconf/user .config/dconf/user.bkp
rm .config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config .config/dconf/user


sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
rm .config/comp-2-1/compiz config/config; dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I fumbled around with Nvidia drivers and this black screen issue for two days. And I fell into this pit because of the 14.04 upgrade from 12.04. Grrr!

The original issue I was trying to resolve was the high cpu utilization of firefox, compiz & Xorg which made the graphics fairly unusable. After attempting to resolve that issue by upgrading the Nvidia driver, all went south and the black screen of death ensued.

Here's some commands that speak to my desktop configuration in case that helps...

"lshw" command produces:

```
description: Mini Tower Computer
product: OptiPlex GX270
```

"lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12" command produces:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x]
```

"wmctrl -m" command produces:

```
Name: Metacity
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

At the end of the day, I'm not 100% sure what worked as I fumbled around so much. Here's what I think did it.

Use the following to get rid of all Nvidia bits and rely on the default driver Nouveau.

```
sudo apt-get purge "nvidia *"
```

Then opt for using Metacity instead of Compiz. Those are the two salient changes I made and the result is a much improved graphics experience with acceptable cpu utilization when doing something such as video streaming from CNNx. Firefox still shows high cpu utilization in "nice top" but that doesn't seem to impact the graphics and especially the video streaming.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me when I was upgrading Ubuntu version. 
Primary user was no more able to log into X.

After having done a backup of ./config I deleted that directory and then I was again able to enter X.

Comment: I tried that too. But, it didn't work. Do you know any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04, while you are in the black screen, you should do the following steps:

Press `Ctrl+Alt+F4` then login using your username and password. Enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge gdm3
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gdm3
```

If it displays a warning, then choose `gdm3` with arrow keys and press enter.

If it didn't, then type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

then:

```
sudo service gdm3 start
```

then restart from your Ubuntu login screen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this ended up being xfwm4's (Xfce's compositor) fault.

Since version 4.13.2 it is using GLX for vsync, and that was somehow not working on my geforce 7100. Switching to Xpresent vblank_mode fixed it for me.

I guess like 2019 additions could not explain 2013 failures, but perhaps mutter, kwin or compiz may have hit a similar issue back then already (especially if like Ubuntu with the latter you were trying to abandon X11)