# How to browse file from sudoer account from guest account?

Tags: ubuntu, file-browser

As I've mentioned earlier, I have been facing problem regarding [isues with loging in with my primary account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101261/how-to-solve-problem-related-to-black-screen-with-cursor-only-after-loging-in). I want to browse my files from that primary account using guest account. Is there any way to do that without logging in into primary account? If yes, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

1. If files are world readable, then yes. `cd ~username`
2. If files are group readable, by other user, then yes. `cd ~username`
3. If other account has sudo rights, then yes: `sudo -u username bash`
4. If you know password of account, then yes: `su username`

If all that fails, there is the live CD. Boot up off a live CD, you can do anything from that, as long as the files are not encrypted with a forgotten key.

Option 4 will work for you. 1-3 may also work.

Comment: guest-sIaazX@dell-Inspiron-3421:/home/dell$ sudo -u dell bash
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted


on using step 2, I got like this.

Comment: don't know, but option 4 should work. You only need the password of the account you are trying to get into.

Comment: Will it work even though I've problem regarding GUI?

Comment: Just try it....

Comment: It did work. :)